# get controls in ContentPlaceHolder asp.net with for each

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, master-pages, contentplaceholder

i have an asp form with masterpage and ContentPlaceHolder
i want to find all controls(checkbox,textbox,lable,...) in my page
i do that(without masterpage) normal

```
 Dim c As Control
    For Each c In Page.Controls
        For Each childc In c.Controls
                If CType(childc, TextBox).Text <> "" Then
```

but this code do not answer with masterpage
i dont need this code

```
TextBox TB=Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("textbox1") as TextBox;
```

beacuse i want all controls

Comment: You can start with `FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").Controls` instead of `Page.Controls`. But that won't work with nested control (like in a `Panel` or even a `GridView`). Why do you need it. Search at the right place instead of looping all child controls.

Comment: thanks i have about 60 control(textbox,drp,chk,...) and database i want when user click send button from this for-loop search all control and save values in database i do that without masterpage correctly but i cant do now i test your solution and chane page.control but visual studio say error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this. Loop through all controls, check their `Type` in loop iteration, based on your case, take action or get value and operate on them.

```
For Each c In Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").Controls
    If TypeOf c Is TextBox Then
        Dim text As TextBox = CType(c, TextBox)
        ' Write code textbox handling
    End If
    If TypeOf c Is CheckBox Then
        Dim chk As CheckBox = CType(c, CheckBox)
        ' Write code checkbox handling
    End If
    If TypeOf c Is DropDownList Then
        Dim ddl As DropDownList = CType(c, DropDownList)
        ' Write code Dropdownlist handling
    End If
Next
```